# JSX/Photoshop: app.activeDocument.saveAs() returning error

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, photoshop, photoshop-script, jsx

I'm trying to save the `activeDocument` as a .psd but its returning this error

> ERROR: General Photoshop error occurred. This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.

### my script:

```
#target photoshop

var fileRef = new File(app.path.toString() + "/Samples/template.psd");
var docRef = open(fileRef);

//target text layer
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Text");

//user input
var newText = prompt("Editing " + layerRef.name, "enter new text: ");

//change contents
layerRef.textItem.contents = newText;

//save
var savePath = "/Samples/" + newText + ".psd";
var saveFile = new File(savePath);
var saveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
saveOptions.alphaChannels = false;
saveOptions.annotations = false;
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
saveOptions.layers = true;
saveOptions.spotColors = false;

app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
app.activeDocument.close();
```

what I want to do is basically, duplicate a template file over and over, only replacing the contents of a text layer then saving it under the string I replace in the text layer.

any tips or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Resolved

I fixed my problem, by a work around. I moved both the script and the template file into the Photoshop directory and added `app.path.toString()` to the `saveFile` output variable. So it seems that the path needed to be converted to a string before saving.

*As of yet I am unsure how to work outside the Photoshop directory* but for me this works so I'm happy. It's a fairly crude but I'm open to suggestion. So if anyone is having a similar issue they can use this for reference.

```
#target photoshop

var loop = true;
var filePath = "/Samples/template.psd";

while(loop) {
  openTemplate(filePath);
  var layerRef = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Text"); //target text layer
  var newText = prompt("Editing " + layerRef.name, "enter new text: "); //user input

  if(newText == "stop") { //stop loop by entering 'stop'
    loop = false;
  }

  layerRef.textItem.contents = newText;
  var savePath = app.path.toString() + "/Samples/" + newText + ".psd";
  var saveFile = new File(savePath);
  savePSD(saveFile);
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

function openTemplate(filePath) { //open template.psd
  var fileRef = new File(app.path.toString() + filePath);
  var docRef = open(fileRef);
}

function savePSD(saveFile) { //saveas newText.psd
  var saveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
  saveOptions.alphaChannels = false;
  saveOptions.annotations = false;
  saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  saveOptions.layers = true;
  saveOptions.spotColors = false;
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem with your original attempt is that you are not specifying a full path.  I always provide a full path - even if it is just to a temporary location like '/c/temp/myfile.psd'.

Answer (score 0):

`app.path` returns a [`File`](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Core/File.html) object, *not* a string. In your case, you most likely want the platform-specific fullpath string:

```js
var appPath = app.path.fsName; // "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2022"
```

Regardless if paths are correct, if you're attempting to save anything to a directory located inside the Photoshop installation directory, you will probably need to run Photoshop as administrator.